# Local source of nuget packages doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget, nuget-package-restore

After opened the project in another computer and run it on **VS Code**, the following problem occurred:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\NuGet.targets(121,5): error : The 
local source C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\' 
doesn't exist.
```

I found the solution for the VS but no VS Code.

Comment: I intentionally want to point to that path which may or may not exist, is it possible to tell nuget to stop freaking out and just ignore it if the folder doesnt exist?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The package source is probably defined in `%appdata%\nuget\nuget.config`. Edit this file in your favourite xml/text editor (VSCode perhaps?). You should see under a package sources element an add element that adds that file path. Comment out or delete that line.

If it's not in that file, try running `dotnet restore --verbosity normal` or just `dotnet restore -v n`. If you still only get an error message, try running `dotnet new nugetconfig`, or temporarily create the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\` directory. NuGet, with normal verbosity, outputs the list of all `nuget.config` files that were read. Open each one until you find which one defines the local source that does not exist, so you can edit it and remove it. Or just keep the empty directory.

It's also possible that the package source is defined in a MSBuild file, rather than a `nuget.config` file. If that's the case, you might need to run `dotnet msbuild -pp` to generate a pre-processed file (the msbuild with all imports evaluated to create a single, "stand-alone" msbuild file). You then search that file for the path that doesn't exist, then scroll up until you find a comment saying what file it was defined in. You then then choose whether you edit that file.

However, it may just be easier to create an empty directory at the path.

Comment: The 'dotnet new nugetconfig' did the trick for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Editing nuget.config works for me. Do you know why did this happen in the first place ?

Comment: I had this problem and it turned out that my Nuget.config file was in a `.nuget` folder.  Once I relocated the file to the solution folder, the issue resolved.  This link provides some additional information.  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior)

Comment: I had to open Package source options and update a custom package source there.

Comment: It happened when I got fed up with Visual Studio, decided to use Rider and deleted Visual Studio. This answer helped me to fix the problem.

Comment: The 'dotnet new nugetconfig' did the trick for me too. Thanks

Comment: Deleting the offending package source in the `Nuget.config` file resolved the issue. I had to restart VS though.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar error preventing `nuget restore` command from working but with a different path:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\NuGet.targets(132,5): error : The local source C:\work\nuget doesn't exist.`

I fixed it by removing that path from:

`Visual Studio ▶ Tools ▶ Options ▶ Nuget Package Manager ▶ Package Sources`

### Update:

On macOS and Linux you may delete `~/.nuget`

Comment: I had a similar error but with a different path: %appdata%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config. Editing this config fixed my error

Comment: Where is this file on macOS and Linux?

Comment: @AaronFranke probably here for macOS: `/usr/local/share/dotnet/` if ARM64 and `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet/` if x64, or maybe here: `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`. And for Linux: `~/.dotnet`

Comment: I ended up deleting `~/.nuget` on macOS and this worked.

Answer (score 14):

Open a PowerShell window and enter the following code:
**dotnet new nugetconfig**

Answer (score 9):

I have used more visual method for resolving this issue look

✍edit1: Possible reason, your project may have **offline packages** referenced to your very first computer. And than, when you go trough another computer, it cant recognise the local source path of your offline packages.

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]
4. [image: List item]
   it is done!

Answer (score 7):

Although the error seems not to be related to nuget, it is actually related.

Open PowerShell and run the following command:

```
dotnet new nugetconfig
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the message says that the folder doesn't exist, I created it, and the problem disappeared. Yes, it was so simple like that.

BTW there is a discussion on GitHub on similar trouble, and [Rob Relya from Microsoft wrote](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8264#issuecomment-506023479):

> This is by design behavior. We fail restore if any of your sources are not reachable.
> We don't want to create a folder for you, in case it was a typo.

From my point of view, it's OK.

Comment: Thanks! The command above or the other solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue on DevOps (image 1,2) .net core restore task. I resolved this by just removing the Offline package reference (image 3) from the NuGet.config file.

image 1
[image]

image 2
[image]

image 3
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble understanding the answers, maybe some of them had the solution. What helped me in the end:

```
I edited C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
and removed <packageSources> with the value "..\NuGet.Config"
```

Not sure how it got there, the actual value might be different for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading my dontet MVC project from .Net core 2.2 to 3.1 and adding a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration.
when I had this issue. All I did is removed the "add key="Local" value=".References" from nuget.config and the issue is solved. I was able to reference the package,

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error.

> error NU1301: The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages' doesn't exist.

Earlier I accidentally deleted the entire shared folder itself( drive was full, so was cleaning up) and so the error.

After reading the @zivkan's answer at the top, I created a file by name NuGetPackages. But that did not solve the problem, because we need to create a folder(directory), not file. So after creating a directory, by name NuGetPackages, dotnet restore worked again.

Of course you need admin permission to create that folder.